# Where did Quick Ben learn how to soul transfer?

Tags: malazan

Throughout [The Malazan Book of the Fallen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malazan_Book_of_the_Fallen) we are shown that Quick Ben knows the lost art of soul transfer. I was wondering how he learned it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any definitive answer, as the books (referring to the Malazan Book of the Fallen series) do not directly indicate where he got the ability. As you said, it is a lost art as described [here](http://malazan.wikia.com/wiki/Ben_Adaephon_Delat), so the chances of Ben learning the art from anyone other than an ascendant would be rare. Also, the Holy Falah'd's Mage cabal did not practice arts in the warren of Kurald Galain [described here](http://malazan.wikia.com/wiki/Ben_Adaephon_Delat), so he didn't pick it up there. I would wager that he developed the ability through experimentation and through his own mental skills, as he is described as just slightly less intelligent than Kruppe, and that he has been practicing using warrens since the age of 10.

Comment: This seems likely, since there are others who practise soul shifting: the Wickan Shamans and also Coltaine.

Comment: Are you referring to the end of the second book where he is taken by the crows? No spoilers, I'm busy with book 8 :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I am referring to. It will be difficult for me to spoiler you, since I am currently reading Memories of Ice (3rd book).

Comment: I never thought of that scene as soul shifting, more like soul transfer or something different, but it's an interesting perspective.