# How is Quick Ben able to draw on Kurald Galain

Tags: malazan

I thought of this after reading nine9's answer to my question "[Where did Quick Ben learn how to soul transfer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72476/where-did-quick-ben-learn-how-to-soul-transfer)"
Kurald Galain is the warren used for soul transfer but it's not a warren normally accessible to humans. What's more it's not even one of Quick's many warrens.
How could Quick Ben, and by extension Tattersail, use Kurald Galain to soul transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kurald Galain was the warren of darkness and was used by the Tiste Andii; although Erikson has not confirmed (AFAIK) it is speculated that one of the souls in Quick was an Andii (only nine are confirmed for certain), so hence he probably has access via that soul.

This is discussed some on the Malazan Empire forum here: http://forum.malazanempire.com/topic/18163-does-quick-ben-have-a-tiste-andii-soul-within/

Also, and a spoiler for *The Crippled God*:

> In TCG Quick visits the Spar of Andii, and speaks with a not-visible "Mother", who may or may not be Mother Dark.  This may confirm the speculation.

Comment: Thanks, probably the best answer I'll get. Still doesn't answer how Tattersail was able to use it when she possessed Nightchill's remains.

Answer (score 1):

Spoiler alert: The Tattersail event may have something to do with Nighchill being the elder god previously known as Sister of Cold Nights. As I understand it, she was either of the species known now as "The Shake" (before the bloodline was watered down by human blood in Lether) or related to the shake in some other manner. Either way, the shake had access to Kurald Galain (even though they are not Tiste Andii) so it's reasonable to assume she did as well. That's the best theory I have, hope it helps.